# WinSxS folder Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm new around here and I'm seeking a bit of knowledge from more experienced admins and users around here :D

Where I work we have several WS2016 up on virual machines, we would love to manage the space of the virtual drives in the best way possible in order to not have to increase them every 2 or 3 months.

Plus we need to run several updates asap.

In a thread we read that running updates on WS2016 could be a pain (they could take up to 5 or 6 hours).

We read that cleaning the WinSxS folder could help in speeding up this process (even if this task could take several hours...but it will not require a reboot or long log off/in process so the services will not be stopped).

Plus it can save quite some good space (if the WinSxS folder is for example 20Gb it cuts it around 10Gb)

So we made a script that uses the dism.exe command and checks the last update: if this is older than 30 days it launches the AnalyzeComponentStore and if the cleaning is recommended it launches the StartComponentCleanup. (I can share the script it if some of you want to check it)

Now the real question...based on your experience could this cleaning process compromise the stability of the System or lead to other problems?

I've runned in on my personal PC at home and at work and it seems that everything is fine....but we'd like to be 100% sure of what we are doing!

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

1. Nobody does this.
2. Windows has a built-in scheduled task that cleans up the component store.
3. Provision your virtual machines so that you're not unnecessarily worrying about disk space. Don't provision disk space so "tightly" that this is a concern.

How large are your virtual machine disks?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/clean-up-the-winsxs-folder

Comment: The fact is that the built-in scheduled task has 1 hour time out...so if the process takes more than one hour it does a rollback so it never cleans the folder. The virtual disks have from 40 to 60gb of dedicated space atm.

Comment: The article states that if you run the task (manually) it will run for only 1 hour. I don't see anything in that article that states it will perform a rollback if the manually started task does not complete in 1 hour. That being said, let Windows manage and run the task as it's designed to do. Provision your virtual disks to account for a reasonable amount of WinSXS growth. Perhaps 80 to 100 GB.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the suggesions :D